# how to sort strings based on a substring JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, sorting

I have strings like these in an Array:

```
let arr = ["UserA | 3", "UserB | 0", "UserC | 2", "UserD | 1"]
```

Names and their ID's at the end. I'd like to sort it based on their id's at the end, but couldn't come up with a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to extract the last number id using a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) combined with [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

Regular expression: `/\d+(?=\D*$)/`

- \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Positive Lookahead (?=\D*$)
  Assert that the Regex below matches
  \D matches any character that's not a digit (equivalent to [^0-9])
- * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

And finally use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/sort)

Code:

```js
const arr = ["UserE | 2020", "UserA | 3", "UserB | 0", "UserC | 2", "UserD | 1"]
const getId = s => +s.match(/\d+(?=\D*$)/)[0] 

arr.sort((a, b) => getId(a) - getId(b))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks Yosvel, it works perfectly now. If you don't mind, could you explain what each of those elements in the regex do? I don't know much about them. Or do you know a source where I could look them up?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?retiredLocale=vi), defining a custom `compareFunction` function in this scheme:

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a value > than 0, sort b before a.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a value < than 0, sort a before b.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, a and b are considered equal.

Like this:

```js
let arr = ["UserA | 3", "UserB | 0", "UserC | 2", "UserD | 1", "UserE | 2020"];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.split(" | ")[1] - b.split(" | ")[1]);

console.log(arr);
```